# Cant apt update on kali nethunter termux

Tags: linux, android, apt

When I install Kali NetHunter with this [git](https://github.com/Hax4us/Nethunter-In-Termux), I start NetHunter but I am unable to execute `apt update`. Instead, I get the following error:

[image: Image of error. The screenshot shows an output log to the screen, where a file, titled contents, arm 64, dot g z, has an unexpected size]

I have tried `apt-key` and even edited the DNS resolv config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot shows that files obtained from the repository don't match the expected size, and indicates a potential explanation: `Mirror sync in progress?`. That could be what's happening (or what *happened*). I.e., your local metadata for a file in the repository says that the size is "5," but by the time the file is downloaded, a mirror sync is in progress on the other end and the size is now "7".

**However**, you've mentioned making some other changes, and it's also visible in the screenshot that you ran:

`echo "deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib" > /etc/apt/sources.list`

That singular `>` character causes `/etc/apt/sources.list` to get overwritten with only `deb https://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib`. It's possible/likely that there were other entries in `/etc/apt/source.list` prior to running this command.

At a minimum, you could try running `apt-get update`, which should get the latest mirror metadata (for the single entry you now have in `/etc/apt/sources.list`), and then try running `apt update` again.

However, **I'd advise starting over and stopping at the first hiccup you see**.

Comment: thank you so much it worked like a charm